# Node js Puppeteer - MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm creating many browsers and loading pages in parallel and stumbled along the following message after 12 browsers have been opened and loaded:

> (node:21888) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory
> leak detected. 11 SIGINT listeners added to [process]. Use
> emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.

Other than removing the listeners from the process after use of each browser I haven't found a way to solve this?

Comment: I rather doubt that `parentPort.postMessage()` is installing a listender for SIGINT every time you call it unless Bree has somehow taken that over (which I don't see in its code).  How many worker threads are you starting?  Are you starting 10 or more worker threads?

Comment: @jfriend00 turns out it was indeed nothing to do with worker thread code or bree and was actually down to a silly mistake I made with not closing the browser. I've updated the question and added an answer to help anyone that might stumble over the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

This was caused by not closing the browser after use, each browser created adds SIGINT, SIGUP and SIGTERM listeners to the process they were started in.

To fix make sure to close the browser and **await** on the function.

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
// Processing   
await browser.close();
```